# Why does my ASP.NET Razor Pages form give ERR_FAILED when my wife runs it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

My wife and I created this Razor page:

```
@page
@model FurWorld.Pages.PetProfileModel
@{
}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>My first name:</td>
            <td><input asp-for="FirstName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>My pet's name:</td>
            <td><input asp-for="PetName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>My pet's age:</td>
            <td><input asp-for="PetAge"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>My pet's location:</td>
            <td><input asp-for="Location"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>My pet's favorite Toy:</td>
            <td><input asp-for="PetFavoriteToy"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>About Us Story:</td>
            <td><textarea asp-for="AboutUs"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>upload a photo</td>
            <td><input asp-for="Photo" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>upload a video</td>
            <td><input asp-for="Video" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

With this code-behind:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using IOFile = System.IO.File;

namespace FurWorld.Pages
{
    public class PetProfileModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            if (Photo is not null)
            {
                // read the photo into a byte array
                var photoStream = Photo.OpenReadStream();
                byte[] b;
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(photoStream))
                {
                    b = br.ReadBytes((int)Photo.Length);
                }

                // find/create the photos directory
                if (!Directory.Exists("Photos"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("Photos");
                }

                // write the file to disk
                using (FileStream fs = IOFile.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("Photos", Photo.FileName)))
                {
                    fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string PetName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public int PetAge { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string PetFavoriteToy { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string AboutUs { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile Video { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can upload a file just fine on my PC, and it saves into the Photos folder. However when my wife runs it on her PC, she gets this error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at https://localhost:7204/PetProfile might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_FAILED

Why would it work for me and not for her? She tried updating Windows and Visual Studio, and installing any Windows components that I have installed that she was missing. Could it have something to do with her running Windows 10 Home while I have Windows 10 Professional? Or maybe there's some Visual Studio component that she needs? When she looked in the Chrome error console (she also tried it in Edge), she saw that the request for PetProfile failed and it had something to do with an anti-forgery token - but I don't have such an error, and adding `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the form didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You said your project works well in your pc, but not works in another pc. And you can try below steps to solve the issue.

**Steps:**

1. Make sure the project can work well and copy the whole project file.
2. Paste it in your another pc
3. Delete `.vs`, `bin`,`obj` folder, if can't see the `.vs` folder, please enable `Show hidden files and folders`.
4. Rebuild the project and it should be works well.

---

**Analysis:**

1. After you follow the steps above, and the issue still occurs. Please use delete all the file mentioned above, and use `dotnet cli` to run it.
2. If we can run it by `dotnet cli`, and reason should relate to Visual Studio, and please update it to latest version.
3. If we can't run it by `dotnet cli`, and should relate to Windows OS version. You can test it in another pc (`Professional`) to improve it.